# Working in mysql with foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I want to create a mysql database with foreign keys. But when i insert some test data i notice that when i look in tables tblcontact and tbladdress my foreign key is null. I know its a basic question but can you give some suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE tblCustomers (
customerID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
vat VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
customerVisible varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'T'
); 


CREATE TABLE tblContact (
contactID INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(100),
phone VARCHAR(100),
customerID int,
CONSTRAINT FK_customerID FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES tblCustomers(customerID) 
);

CREATE TABLE tblAddress (
addressID INT NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
street VARCHAR(100),
houseNumber VARCHAR(15),
city VARCHAR (100),
country VARCHAR (100),
customerID int,
CONSTRAINT FK_customerIDa  FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES tblCustomers(customerID)
);

 INSERT INTO tblCustomers (firstname, lastname,vat) VALUES ("John","Doe","UV45856855");
INSERT INTO tblContact (email, phone) VALUES ("0000001","Johndoe@gmail.com");
INSERT INTO tblAddress (street,housenumber,city,country) VALUES ("berkenlaan","1a","Harelbeke","Belgie");
```

Comment: So you expect the DB somehow infer the customer id from an email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the concept of foreign keys.. A foreign key is a key used to link two tables together.. so in order to relate a particular row to its parent row you should enter its reference (primary key of parent) in child.

Its is not automatic.. you have to enter the `customerId` of `tblCustomer` in `tblAddress` and `tblContact` manually to contain the dependency.

You didnt do it in your code.. thats why you are getting null. How will mysql know that the data you are putting in `tblAddress` and `tblContact` are related to specific Customer?

If you want this to happen automatically you can create a trigger using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Example:-

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblAddress_auto_insert AFTER INSERT ON `tblAddress` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO tblAddress (customerID) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
END;
```

Similarly do it for `tblContact`.

HTH

Comment: When i try to use your trigger it gives me an syntax error at INSERT INTO tblAddress (customerID) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID()); missing 'semicolon'

Comment: I got the following error: 12:14:53 CREATE TRIGGER tblAddress_auto_insert AFTER INSERT ON `tblAddress`  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN      INSERT INTO tblAddress (customerID) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID()) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 0.000 sec

Comment: Great i found i have to use delimiter But now i get following error while insert new date into tblAddress 12:21:32 INSERT INTO tblAddress (street,housenumber,city,country) VALUES ("berkenlaan","1a","Harelbeke","Belgie") Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'tbladdress' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. 0.031 sec

Comment: great.. delimiter where?

Comment: DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER tblAddress_auto_insert AFTER INSERT ON    `tblAddress` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO tblAddress (customerID) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
END; //

DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for this may be your default database engine is MyISAM.
Change it to InnoDB while creating the database or manually using phpmyadmin.

Comment: I alter the tables to innoDB but i still get the the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting any values in the referenced columns in tblcontact and tbladdress. These columns would not populated automatically. You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO tblCustomers (firstname, lastname,vat) 
VALUES ("John","Doe","UV45856855");
INSERT INTO tblContact (customerID,email, phone) 
VALUES ((SELECT DISTINCT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM tblCustomers), "0000001","Johndoe@gmail.com");
INSERT INTO tblAddress (customerID,street,housenumber,city,country) 
VALUES ((SELECT DISTINCT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM tblCustomers), "berkenlaan","1a","Harelbeke","Belgie");
```

Another way can be from the server side language you are using.
You can create a query object of the first insert and then can find its last inserted value.